# Magento how add product to static cms module page

Tags: magento

I have magento with cms module and I created static page, now I would like to add a some of products to this page.

How can I do that?

i've found this plugin http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-add-products-to-cms.html but i want to do it by myself

Answer (score 1):

You can add products from a category to a CMS page by ading this to your cms content - disable the wysiwyg editor when you paste it in;

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="123" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Just change the category ID to the one you want.